# Is This Type of Compled Layout Possible With UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Is this type of layout possible with UICollectionViews? It is completely dynamic where there can be many rows, many columns inside those rows, many sections inside those columns, and many cells (controls) inside those sections.

This is up and running well on web and Android but the iOS implementation which uses stackviews upon stackviews will take 10-20 seconds to layout more complex layouts which might have 50 cells.

I have tested UICollectionView with either one column for phone or two column for layout and it works well but I would still like to keep the dynamic layout like pictured below.

Thanks for any help provided.

UICollectionView:

[image]

Comment: To answer your immediate question - it is possible. You can even try to do it by having stackviews inside collection view cells. The added benefit of collection view is that it won't create cells that are offscreen initially, so your view controller will probably load faster.

Comment: That means what i have labeled as section in the above diagram would now be the cell. This is would work if each cell only had maybe four or five views in them but users can incorrectly setup these layouts and put 100 views in each cell which would mean 100 would be loaded and initialized of only say six appeared on the screen.

Comment: This question might actually help, with Android you can set recyclerview to wrap content and put it inside a parent scrollable item. If i have a collection view where the sections are cells and a table view where the cells are the views will the table views correctly load data?